# How to say "Do you know me"?

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-request

Hello everyone I new here in the language korean I would like know if this way is correct say "Do you know me " in korean

I alway say this way "**no na ara**" `너, 나 알아?`

someone that speak korean or a  native can tell me if is correct say this way?

I hope that my question is good for you  is only I new with this language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"너 나 알아?" is not wrong but very rude, unless you're a kid.

Instead you can say "저 아세요?"

- 저 is a polite form of 나.
- There's no reason for explicit "너" (or "당신") to denote "you": after all, the question only makes sense as "do *you* know me?".  In fact, using even 당신 would make the sentence sound more rude.  (Modern Korean doesn't really have a good polite form for singular "you".)
- 아세요 is made of 알- "know (알다)" + -시- polite suffix for the subject + -어요 moderately polite sentence ending form (can be a question or a declarative sentence).  So you're being polite to the listener *and* the subject of the sentence, and in this case they both happen to be "you".